# Exporting web request to CSV does not create table headers properly

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm calling a web API that is returning an XML. A single element of this XML oputput contains an entire table of data. Meaning it looks like this:

```xml
<MasterElement>
    <ElementName>
  TableHeader1 TableHeader2 TableHeader3 Value1,1 Value1,2 Value1,3 Value2,1 Value2,2 etc...
 </ElementName>
</MasterElement>
```

When I use `Invoke-WebRequest` then output to file (CSV), if I go and open the actual file, it looks like a normal Excel table.

This is the code I use:

```bsh
$uri = "url"
$Report = Invoke-WebRequest -Method 'get' -ContentType "application/xml" -Uri $uri

$FilePath = "C:\Users\user\Documents\file.csv"

$Results = ([xml]$Report.Content).MasterElement.ChildElement.InnerText |
           Out-File -FilePath $FilePath

$CSV = Import-Csv -Path $FilePath
```

But, if I try to `Import-Csv` and then read specific columns (e.g.: `$CSV[0]."TableHeader1"`) instead of recognizing each column on its own, it's reading the entire row of column headers as a single string.

Comment: It sounds like your csv is not in the correct format. Is there a reason why you are using `out-file` and not `export-csv` ?

Comment: Yes, if I use that it just gives me the length of the file content and not the actual data

Comment: @RevBlue    Try `$Results=([xml]$Report.Content).MasterElement.ChildElement.InnerText | ConvertTo-CSV | Out-File -FilePath $FilePath`

Comment: @techguy10289 unfortunately it still just gives me the length of the text data only and not the content

Comment: The data in your XML seems to be a single row where the first tokens specify the headers and the data entries are marked with a prefix `value<rownumber>,`. You need to transform that into a list of objects or data rows to be able to export it as a CSV. Are all tokens in that line separated by spaces? Or are there different delimiters for fields and rows (like space and tab)? Is the number of columns known?

Comment: Separated by spaces. Known number of columns. Does this allow me some manipulation that will help solve this?

Comment: You could parse the extracted data line like this: `... | Select-String '(\S+) (\S+) (\S+)' -AllMatches` and then construct strings or custom objects from the captured groups.